# JSP, button and JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I'm new to jsp and jstl tags. My goal is to make a 'Roll a dice' program, which can be started with button click or reset with another button. How do I use `<c:choose>` on button click? Here is my code so far:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test ="$pageContext.session.heita">  
        noppa.heita();
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="$pageContext.session.nollaa">
        noppa.nollaa();
        out.println("Noppaa ei ole heitetty");
    </c:when>    
</c:choose>
<%-- Käytetään noppa-olion getTulos() -metodia--%>

Olet heittänyt: <%= noppa.getHeitot()%> kertaa<br>
Silmäluvuksi tuli: <%= noppa.getTulos()%><br>

Heittojen summa on nyt: <%= noppa.getSumma()%><br>

Heittojen keskiarvo on: <%=noppa.getKeskiArvo()%><br>
<br>

<button type="submit" value=<c:set var="heita" value="${noppa.heita()}"></c:set>>Heitä</Button>
```

So, this is written mostly in finnish, but i'll try to translate.  is used to select user input via button. "heita" means throw and "nollaa" means reset.

Others here means it's working(those "olet heittänyt" etc).

edit 1: l'm using jsp bean with not exactly a bean class.

```
public class Noppa {

    private double summa = 0;
    private double tulos = 0;
    private double heitot = 0;
    private double keskiArvo;
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public double getSumma() {
        return summa;
    }

    public double getTulos() {
        return tulos;
    }

    public void heita() {

        heitot += 1;
        System.out.println("Heitot " + heitot);
        tulos = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        summa += tulos;
        setKeskiArvo(heitot);
    }

    public double getHeitot() {

        return heitot;

    }

    public void nollaa() {
        summa = 0;
        heitot = 0;
        keskiArvo = 0;
    }

    public double getKeskiArvo() {
        return keskiArvo;
    }

    public void setKeskiArvo(double keskiArvo) {

        if (heitot <= 1) {

            this.keskiArvo = tulos;

        } else {
            this.keskiArvo = summa / heitot;
            System.out.println("Keskiarvo: " + this.keskiArvo);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write a button click event?

Comment: Should that be a form submit?  Or are you thinking it's a Javascript onclick event handler?

Comment: Please, translate all the code you post in English. I would strongly advise keeping all your code in English BTW.